# How to shorten URL with passed-in PHP variables generated from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I've been using the code from this YouTube video: http://youtu.be/8GSQSYXv_TQ  and it works perfectly for what I'm doing.  Essentially, I'm saving JSON content to variables and passing them another page.  Unfortunately, when passed to another page, the passed in variables include all of the content of the passed in JSON "node".  For example,

`<a href="detail.php?title=$title&description=$description&link=$link".....>`

Passes this URL into the `detail.php` page:

`http:....../detail.php?title=SOME REALLY LONG TITLE&description=THIS IS AN ENTIRE PARAGRAPH OF TEXT. BLAHBLAH.........` and so forth.

Is there a way to truncate all of this, encrypt the passed in data, or something?  I think I read somewhere that I could save it as a session variable, but I'm not sure if this is correct or not.

Thanks for reading.  I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Why don't you use POST instead of GET?

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I'm not using forms.  The information is being passed through via <a href=...

Comment: json has no problem posting the variables. POST does not have to be from forms.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve your issue...

Use POST instead OF GET if possible.

Use you can store all of the data in the $_SESSION variable like so...

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['title'] = $title;
$_SESSION['description'] = $description;
$_SESSION['link'] = $link;
```

Then on any page you go to you can access it with...

```
session_start();
$title = $_SESSION['title']
$description = $_SESSION['description'];
$link = $_SESSION['link'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go for using sessions , because it seems to be more easy and fast to implement.

Another solution i'll suggest is write a form with the params in hidden type fields and say to this form to post these informations into your another page.

if you want to use sessions i'll suggest you do this way:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = serialize (array("param1" => $value, "param2" => $value2));
```

dont forget to unserialize() before use the info.

Comment: Thank you for replying!  How would I write the _GET code on my destination page when using this code?  Sorry, I'm new to using Sessions.  I've only dipped my toes in it.

Comment: In the destination page you would do something like: "session_start(); $params = unserialize($_SESSION['data'])";" then in $params variable you got the same array as the previous page.